# Creating loop with particular behaviour depending on data length

Tags: python, loops

In my program I have a part of code that uses an `Estimated Moving Average` (`EMA`) 4 times, but each time with different length. The program uses one or more `EMA`s depending on how much data it gets.

For now the code is not looped, just copy pasted with minor tweeks. That makes making changes difficult because I have to change everything 4 times.

Can somebody help me loop the code in such a way it wont loose it behaviour pattern. The mock-up code is presented here:

```
import random
import numpy as np

zakres=[5,10,15,20]
data=[]

def SI_sma(data, zakres):
    weights=np.ones((zakres,))/zakres
    smas=np.convolve(data, weights, 'valid')
    return smas

def SI_ema(data, zakres):
    weights_ema = np.exp(np.linspace(-1.,0.,zakres))
    weights_ema /= weights_ema.sum()
    ema=np.convolve(data,weights_ema)[:len(data)]
    ema[:zakres]=ema[zakres]
    return ema

while True:
    data.append(random.uniform(0,100))
    print(len(data))
    if len(data)>zakres[0]:
        smas=SI_sma(data=data, zakres=zakres[0])
        ema=SI_ema(data=data, zakres=zakres[0])
        print(smas[-1]) #calc using smas
        print(ema[-1])  #calc using ema1
    if len(data)>zakres[1]:
        ema2=SI_ema(data=data, zakres=zakres[1])
        print(ema2[-1]) #calc using ema2
    if len(data)>zakres[2]:
        ema3=SI_ema(data=data, zakres=zakres[2])
        print(ema3[-1]) #calc using ema3
    if len(data)>zakres[3]:
        ema4=SI_ema(data=data, zakres=zakres[3])
        print(ema4[-1]) #calc using ema4
    input("press a key")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable number of variables is usually a bad idea. As you have found, it can make maintaining code cumbersome and error-prone. Instead, you can define a `dict` of results and use a `for` loop to iterate scenarios, defining `len(data)` just once.

```
ema = {}

while True:
    data.append(random.uniform(0,100))
    n = len(data)
    for i, val in enumerate(zakres):
        if n > val:
            if i == 1:
                smas = SI_sma(data=data, zakres=val)
            ema[i] = SI_ema(data=data, zakres=val)
```

You can then access results via `ema[0]`, ..., `ema[3]` as required.